# Connecting Umbraco backend with on premise AD authentication from Azure

Tags: azure, active-directory, ldap, umbraco, umbraco7

We are migrating our web applications from an on premise environment to Azure app services.

One of the webapps is causing a little bit of trouble, it's an Umbraco website that uses LDAP for connecting with an external AD for backend authentication.

It appears the authentication server is not being called.

The client receives the following message (after a while of waiting):

```
{  
  "Message":"An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage":"The server is not operational.\r\n",
  "ExceptionType":"System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException",
  "StackTrace":" at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)\r\n at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()\r\n at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.RefreshCache()\r\n at System.Web.Security.DirectoryInformation..ctor(String adspath, NetworkCredential credentials, String connProtection, Int32 clientSearchTimeout, Int32 serverSearchTimeout, Boolean enablePasswordReset)"
}
```

Unfortunately I'm not an Azure expert and searching for this problem didn't result in any solutions. 
From the error message I can conclude that the on premise cannnot be reached from Azure, but I don't understand why.

Is Azure blocking the 636 port?
Is this setup even possibly in Miscrosoft Azure?

Any pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated.